# PHP - Post Media / Image to twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I got code changing twitter status, unfortunately it does not posting image.

Please review my code and help me posting image with text.

```
 $consumerKey    = '';
 $consumerSecret = '';
 $oAuthToken     = '';
 $oAuthSecret    = '';

include "OAuth.php";
 include "twitteroauth.php";
 require_once('twitteroauth.php');
 $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken,      $oAuthSecret);
 $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'PHP --> example.co.uk <-- ',  'media[]' => "http://www.balanced-hr.com/wp-     content/uploads/2014/08/majster.jpg"));
 echo "your message has been sent to twitter API";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that you should upload your media first (after creating TwitterOAuth object)

```
$media = $tweet->upload('media/upload', array('media' => 'path_to_your_file'));
```

Then set the parameters of your tweet (like status and media)

```
$parameters = array(
'status' => 'Your Tweet status',
'media_ids' => $media->media_id_string);
```

You can view the docs to upload up to 4 media resources in the same tweet

And then send the tweet with the parameters.

```
$send_tweet = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```

You can see an example using media here: https://twitteroauth.com/
And the statuses/update reference here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: Can you post the log returned by the API?

Comment: not working gettin error syntax error, unexpected ''media_ids'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

Comment: $media = $connection->upload('media/upload', array('media' => 'http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg')); $parameters = [ 'status' = >"tweet" 'media_ids' = > $media->media_id_string ];

Comment: Maybe the comma in the array? ['status' => "tweet" **,** 'media_ids' => $media->

Comment: Don't remove it, the mark must be there, I'll try your code when I'm home :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
```

check the connection first

```
$result = $connection->upload('media/upload', array('media' => 'Relative Path to your media'));

$mediaID = $result->media_id;
$parameters = array('status' => 'First tweet','media_ids' => $mediaID);
$response = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
```

The above code worked in my instance