# Php Twitter Post tweet with media

Tags: php, twitter

With this code, I can upload image and print Media ID but I can't post a tweet with image. Could you help me?

Thanks

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
set_include_path('/home/.....');
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "...",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "...",
    'consumer_key' => "...",
    'consumer_secret' => "..."
);
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);


$file = file_get_contents('aaa.jpg');
$data = base64_encode($file);

// Upload image to twitter
$url = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";
$method = "POST";
$params = array(
"media_data" => $data,
);

$json = $twitter
->buildOauth($url, $method)
->setPostfields($params)
->performRequest();

// Result is a json string
$res = json_decode($json);
// Extract media id
$id = $res->media_id_string;
print_r($id);
```

////// Code is working to this line and can print media id like 213213214123123

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$response = $twitter->setPostfields(
    array('status' => '', 'media_ids' => $id)
)
                    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                    ->performRequest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `media_id` value can be used to create a Tweet with an attached photo using the `statuses/update` endpoint. Use your media_id as a parameter in the  [Statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update.html)

Comment: Sorry I dont understand completely. I think i use  media_id as a parameter in the Statuses/update. What i have to change ? @Gowtham Shiva

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897694/php-post-media-image-to-twitter